# Clock synchronisation of K8s pods in same namespace in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have spawned multiple Kubernetes PODs within same namespace at different times. I would like to know if the clocks of the Kubernetes PODs are synchronized? I have gone through a few posts here, but could not get an idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I good understood your question about synchronization.

If you are asking about clock in `container`, it will be the same as in the `host machine.` It is controlled by the kernel of this machine.

I would suggest you to check [Kubernetes Container Timezone Management](https://medium.com/@yildirimabdrhm/kubernetes-timezone-management-8cc139b01f9d)

However, if you would ask about `Timezone` it is controller by OS layer thus it might be different inside the `container`.

In short, even if pods might be in the same `namespace` clock will be depend on where it was scheduled.

**If this was not what you asked for, please elaborate your question.**

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually I have deployed our application on multiple PODs in EKS cluster. In this regard, actually I would like to know if the clocks on the PODs are in sync or not.

Comment: You asking is it possible that are in the same namespace can have different times inside pod?